# Call static method on parametrized class in Java

Tags: java, class, static, member

I have a list of classes that extend the same superclass, which has a static field called foo:

```
List<Class<? extends SuperClass>> list;
```

how can I access foo on an element of that list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why should

```
Superclass.foo
```

not work? Since it is static, your `List` is completely irrelevant. And also the child classes, since the field exists exactly once in `Superclass`.

Comment: Ok I just realized I messed up my post. What if foo is a method? The point is that the subclasses might override foo because each subclass should return a distinct value.

Comment: Field or method - its just the same here (besides the `()` of course). And since "it" (field or method) is static, it cannot be overriden. Override works only on non-static fields. If you call `Superclass.foo` you _will_ get `Superclass.foo`, even if `Childclass.foo` exists. If you want `Childclass.foo` you will have to say so. And: If there is no `Childclass.foo` but you say so, the compiler will silently make that `Superclass.foo` _at compile time_. But overloading would happen _at runtime_. So don't confuse the compiler's mercy with overriding.

Comment: So if I can't override static members, does that mean there is no way for me to retrieve a value specific to each class at runtime?

Comment: The problems: The question is misleading, due to terms like `Superclass`, "extend" and "overrides" and the implication that there is exactly one field called `foo`. I propose that you open a new question, avoid these wording and show some code (a [SSCCE](sscce.org) perhaps) where your real usecase is made clear explicitly. Then solutions will come up.

Answer (score 3):

You can access a static field foo on a superclass through the class name:

```
 SuperClass.foo
```

A static field has one value across all instances and all subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

The class name and his static member:

```
SuperClass.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to call a static method on a Class, not on a class that's a child of SuperClass.

Say you have a Class Foo that has a static method bar that returns a String.  You can do this:

```
String test = Foo.bar();
```

but you can't do this:

```
String test = Foo.class.bar();
```

What you have in your example would be more like this:

```
Class<? extends SuperClass> classz = Foo.class;
String test = classz.bar(); // same as Foo.class.bar();
```

**Solution:** You should be able to use reflection at this point to call the method:

```
String test = (String) Foo.class.getMethod("bar").invoke(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make foo protected, that way you can access it in a subclass.